# C# project reference setting SpecificVersion = False seems not working

Tags: .net, dll, reflection, assemblyversions

I have the following scenario:

- A.dll version 1.0.0.1
- B.dll version 1.0.0.1 depends of A.dll. The reference is set with SpecificVersion = False

  ```
  <Reference Include="A">
      <HintPath>A.dll</HintPath>
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  </Reference>
  ```
- C.exe loads using `Assembly.LoadFrom("B.dll")` B.dll

If I change the version of A.dll to 1.0.0.2 I get a FileNotFoundException on `Assembly.LoadFrom("B.dll")` saying that it cannot find A.dll 1.0.0.1 (at that moment only A.dll 1.0.02 exists but that should not matter as SpecificVersion is false)

Comment: You just misunderstand what SpecificVersion does.  It only plays a role at compile-time, never at runtime.  The CLR insists on an **exact** match at runtime, a .config file is required to convince it that you are not making a mistake.  You probably are, there are few good reasons to avoid rebuilding B with an updated reference assembly for A.

Comment: @HansPassant: Signatures do not change. It's only that the whole application share the same build number so the only thing that changed is the number :S I thought that the build number was not checked, only the major and minor values. Was I wrong?

Comment: You have good evidence that you are indeed wrong.

Comment: @HansPassant: I see. I don't get why I don't need it in build time but I do in runtime. Any interesting reference you can point me?

Comment: @HansPassant can you please provide link with more details about why CLR insists on exact match?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Assembly Binding Redirection as Hans suggested in his comment:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="someAssembly"
      publicKeyToken="32ab4ba45e0a69a1"
      culture="en-us" />

    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="7.0.0.0" newVersion="8.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Please refer to this link for more info
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19(v=vs.110).aspx